# Wrong Time Given Using date()

Tags: php, date, datetime, time, timezone

How do I return the current time in my time zone? It keeps returning it a day too fast. It's saying that it's Sunday when its Sat. It's 6:30PM and it's saying it 1:30 AM. How can I fix this?

Comment: PHPs [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function returns servers time/date...

Comment: I image your timezone and/or date & time is then simply set incorrectly.

Comment: Either get their IP and convert it to a city/general region that can be translated to a timezone. -- or just use javascript.

Comment: it is giving you the date in GMT.It is not wrong. You just have to get the date in the correct local timezone

Comment: Define ***"my"*** timezone.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

use this code in date function

```
date('g:i:s', time()-18000);
```

with using **time()-18000** you will fix it 
Good luck !

Comment: change -18000 to +18000 to add 5 hours am sure that will help you

Comment: Set the correct timezone at least. Doing small adjustments is not the answer.

Comment: Just hope your timezone doesn't have DST.

Comment: ok i tried it and its still 2 hours fast

Comment: just tell me what is your time zone please if +3 , +4 , +5 or what ! or use this **time()+3600*3** the 3 mean the number of hours to add good luck

Answer (score 0):

Set up default timezone by `date_default_timezone_set('UTC');` and read manual.

Examples: UTC, GMT, Atlantic/Azores

Comment: I fixed it the problem was my sys time. It was set to a different time zone.